# How Yield statement in ruby works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yield

Can someone please show how to correctly format this yield statement, and why my methodology for this yield statement is incorrect? When run, the compiler results in an "undefined method 'length' error. "Test" is the main class.

```
  def bubble_sort_by(array)
    len = array.length - 1
    while len > 0
      for i in(1..len)
        @left = array[i]
        @right = array[i - 1]
        yield
        if @left - @right > 0
           array[i - 1], array[i] = array[i], array[i - 1]
        end
      end
      len -= 1
    end
   p array
end

  Test.bubble_sort_by(%w[hi hello hey]) do |left, right|
    left.length - right.length
  end
```

Comment: If the block were `{ |a,b| a*b }` and `c = yield(2,3)`, `a` and `b` would be assigned values `2` and `3`, respectively, so the block would return `6`, which would be assigned to the variable `c`.

Comment: Thank you for responding, Cary. @CarySwoveland how is " if yield(array[i-1], array[i]) > 1" not the same as the code written above for the if statement.

Comment: No, the body of the block (`left.length - right.length`) only has access to the variables directly passed to it by `yield`, not to any variables or methods that would be accessible within the method doing the yielding (`bubble_sort_by`).

Answer (score 2):

because you need to pass arguments to yield.

try to change the line with yield into: 
`compared = yield @left, @right`
and deal with the `compared` result

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment on the question, `yield` needs to pass values for the block variables. Your code therefore needs to be modified as follows.

```
def bubble_sort_by(array)
    len = array.length - 1
    while len > 0
      for i in(1..len)
        @left = array[i]
        @right = array[i - 1]
        if yield(@left, @right) > 0
          array[i - 1], array[i] = array[i], array[i - 1]
        end
      end
      len -= 1
    end
  array
end

bubble_sort_by(%w[hi hello hey]) do |left, right|
  left.length - right.length
end
  #=> ["hello", "hey", "hi"]
```

If, as here, the block being yielded to has block variables, the values of those variables must be passed as `yield`'s arguments. The value computed by the block is then returned as though `yield` were the invocation of a method.

If you prefer, you could replace the first line with

```
def bubble_sort_by(array, &block)
```

and replace `if yield(@left, @right) > 0` with

```
if block.call(@left, @right) > 0
```

Here `&` converts the bloc to a `Proc` which is held by the variable `block`.

Comment: One small suggestion: would be nice to also explain what you changed and why is needed.

Comment: @Rada, that's a good point. The only reason I didn't elaborate was because I had eariler left an abbreviated explanation in a comment on the question. But you are right; I'll edit my answer.